# FATAL: could not create lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied

Tags: postgresql

I receive error

```
FATAL:  could not create lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

when trying to execute command

```
pg_ctl restart --pgdata "D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\data"
```

Full rights for postgres user to D:\, D:\Program Files\, D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\ and D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\data are set. What else I need to do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I set full access to D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\data to Users group and now it works. Detail are at 
http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/114/pokertracker/cant-connect-db-422617/
(last post).

Comment: Pretty nasty that SO uses rel-nofollow in order to steal all google rep coming from that link, I must say

Answer (score 12):

You need to ensure that the user postgres has write permission to the postgres data_directory configured in postgresql.conf file. In my case `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/` if not add permission with:

```
chmod u+w /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to make ensure that the user `postgres` has right to write & execute /var/run/postgresql

```
sudo chmod 765 /var/run/postgresql  
sudo chown postgres /var/run/postgresql
```

I had this issue due to installing postgres-xc and the solution was to remove it.

pg_ctl is the most common (and recommended) way used to start/stop/etc postgres.

For some reason it was not part of my postgres install.
After duckduckgo'ing a little, I installed postgre-xc which includes pg_ctl.
postgres-xc changed the owner of /var/run/postgresql from postgres to postgres-xc.
This caused lots of headaches and warnings about being unable to lock the pid file.

So, I removed postgres-xc (and reverted the owner of /var/run/postgresql to postgres).

Instead of using pg_ctl, I control postgres using

`service postgresql status`
or
`/etc/init.d/postgresql status`.

Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: The equiv on Windows would be net start postgresql-9.5, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-to-start-postgresql-on-windows

Answer (score 5):

`postgresql service`is logined in `NETWORK SERVICE`, so you must needed make data dir(ie: `"D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\data"`) is full control over to `NETWORK SERVICE` group.

Answer (score -1):

I just added my username to group "postgres"; all went fine

```
sudo adduser your-user-name postgres
```

Ciao